# Git python how to use python script uploaded in github using Linux server?

Tags: python, linux, github

I use a python script in a Linux server like this.

```
$ python /data/script/sample.py iput1.txt input2.txt > output.txt
```

But I want to use this script uploaded in github.

So I what I want to do is

```
$ python https://github.com/mylab/script/sample.py iput1.txt input2.txt > output.txt
```

Like this.

Comment: The question is not clear; what exactly do you want to do? If you want to use the script from GitHub, you need to pull it to your local machine and then run it. 
https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/quickstart/hello-world

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Devang Sanghani](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5833865/devang-sanghani) said you need to get your script local. Therefore clone your repository containing the script.

```
$[~]> git clone https://github.com/mylab/your-repositoy/
$[~]> cd your-repository
$[~/your-repository]> python sample.py iput1.txt input2.txt > output.txt
```